# Is there a way to convert points in a U-V Coordinate system to WGS84 points?

Tags: gis, coordinate-systems, wgs84

I have a file that contains 4 values(X-start, X-end, Y-start, Y-end) that denote the X and Y ranges of a grid. These points are represented in the u-v coordinate system. However I would like to plot them in WGS84 system. Is there a mathematical formula that can help with this conversion ?

Since I had two axis (Azimuth and Elevation axes), I applied the following formula to convert each point in the grid to WGS84. This formula however is giving me really weird results.

x_vector = ( -1 * Az * (math.sin(math.sqrt( Az*Az + El*El )))) / (math.sqrt( Az*Az + El*El ))
y_vector = ( El * (math.sin(math.sqrt( Az*Az + El*El )))) / (math.sqrt( Az*Az + El*El ))

Comment: What is a "U-V coordinate system"? And for coordinate conversion, you may need to explain how large the delta X and delta Y (to see which method we can uses). In any case I recommend you to use proj4 (which exists in many languages) or other libraries. Formulas are misleading: we are working with floating point, so there is requirements to do correct implementation (so without losing precision).